# Glue 2D mesh on a 3D model?

Tags: modeling

I'm totally new to blender and I start trying to do a wizard hat. Since I started, I manage to do pretty much every thing I wanted to do. But I'm starting to struggle.
So what I'm trying to do is pretty obvious, I'm trying to "glue" my plane star on my 3D hat.
I tried "Boolean Union", big failure. And I didn't try to merge on vertices because I don't know how to create a 5 vertices stars on my rounded 3D model.
I didn't find any tutorials or documentation, that's why I writting here, I tried to do it my way but maybe it's not a good one.
If any of you got an idea on how to do that, I'll appreciate !
Cheers.

[image]

Comment: It depends .. do you want the star to be rigid, like a metal badge, with some independent movement? do you want it to be part of the color of the fabric? Or like it's stitched on? All possible, all different.

Comment: Ok I reallize that I'm really a beginner....
I'm not sure of what you mean by the second and third  possibilities but I think I will prefere it to be independant, like a metal badge.
thx for the answer.

Comment: Yeah it should be good ! Thanks guys and sorry for repost so. I probaly don't have the right vocabulary...